plugin in a Adobe Illustrator or Indesign that can embed in a google sheets
How to embed a google sheets( that has imagem, name, location(type) and level) in a adobe project to make a template by the datas of the sheets.
Tried some pluginXLSX in adobe Illustrator and Indesign that didnt work, because have more that 3 informations and a imagem.
